# Failed to register the Microsoft.DevSpaces provider in this subscription

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

I have created AKS cluster and then tried to enable the Azure Dev Spaces for this cluster. On saving the changes I am getting an error saying : Failed to register the Microsoft.DevSpaces provider in this subscription

On checking my permissions I found that I am owner for this resource group but not the subscription.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue

Comment: How do you use the Azure Dev Spaces and which region are you in? And do you check if the Microsoft.DevSpaces registered or your registry it?

Comment: I use it for deploying my project microservices and I have created it in EastUS region

Comment: Do you check if the Microsoft.DevSpaces registered or you registry it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can try to enable devspaces using cli command mentioned as follows.

```
az aks use-dev-spaces -g **ResourceGroup** -n **ClusterName**
```

Comment: Thanks @Saiteja Prattipati for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register  Microsoft.DevSpaces registry in the azure portal for your subscription to get rid of this issue,

Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types).

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for your reply. I checked for Microsoft.DevSpaces and found it registered against the subscription

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-register-resource-provider